# Authentication Sample Bot does not let me authenticate in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I try to get the [Authentication Sample Bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) to work. When I use the Bot in Microsoft Teams, the `OAuthPrompt` seems to render correctly:

[image]

but when I click the button, nothing happens. I see this in the console:

[image]

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Did you create a manifest file for your app? In order to open login URL inside teams pop-up, you need to add the domain of your authentication redirect URL to the validDomains. You can use [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio) if you haven't created manifest file yet. Please have a look at documentation on how to  [Authenticate a user in a Microsoft Teams bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-bot-aad).

Comment: I am using Azure Bot Service Authentication with OAuth Settings like this: `return new OAuthPrompt(
 dialogId_LoginPromptName,
 new OAuthPromptSettings
 {
  ConnectionName = connectionName,
  Text = "Please Sign In",
  Title = "Sign In",
  Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
 });`

Comment: Did you create app manifest?

Comment: Yes I had the manifest, but I did not specify the validDomains. With `"validDomains": [ "token.botframework.com" ]` login seems to be working correctly. I just don't get the token now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just creating an Azure Bot Service 'Bot Channels Registration' is not enough to use bot authentication with Microsoft Teams. You have to have a manifest file zipped and uploaded as a custom app into Microsoft Teams. In that manifest file you have to specify the domain of the Bot Framework token endpoint:

```
"validDomains": [ "token.botframework.com" ]
```